# Название типа в generic функции

Tags: typescript

Я хочу получить название типа с которым работает generic функция.
Сейчас я могу получить это название следующим образом:

```
class Cat {}

function ShowTypeName<T>(constructor: new() => T) {
    console.log(constructor.name);
}

ShowTypeName<Cat>(Cat); // в консоли увидим Cat
```

Есть ли способ избавиться от передачи в функцию типа Cat так, чтобы поведение функции не изменилось? 
Например так:

```
ShowTypeName<Cat>(); // в консоли увидим Cat
```

Можно ли получить название типа из T?

Пробовал что-то вроде такого, но безуспешно:

```
function ShowTypeName<T>() {
    type Constructor = new() => T;
    let t: Constructor = T;
    console.log(t.name);
}
```

Comment: нельзя, это сахар, первый вариант правильный (`ctor.name`)

Comment: Жаль. Спасибо за ответ